# FreeLAN for Virtual LAN Gaming

Tags: networking, lan

I have 2 Windows 10 PCs on different networks and I need to connect them on LAN.

I am using FreeLAN and configured it as follows:

```
 A (host): freelan.exe --security.passphrase "pass" --tap_adapter.ipv4_address_prefix_length 192.168.10.1/24
 B: freelan.exe --security.passphrase "pass" --tap_adapter.ipv4_address_prefix_length 192.168.10.2/24 --fscp.contact A_address:12000
```

I can ping from 192.168.10.1 to 192.168.10.2 and vice versa, but I can not connect them in a LAN game (e.g. Minecraft). I do not know how a game search another on LAN, but could it be that it uses broadcast but is ignored?

Does anyone know how I can make it work?

Regards, and thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you have open the port on the server?  If you can ping between the two machines, then Minecraft on Machine A should be able to connect to the Minecraft server running on Machine B

Comment: @Ramhound In the minecraft example there would not be a server, but a client would open their game on LAN. If both were connected to the same network the game appears, but in different networks with FreeLAN it does not appear. Thank you very much!

Comment: What you describe would still be a server.  Please edit your question, and verify if you have forwarded all required ports, that is still required and might not be possible based on the ISP configuration.